# How to open Child form that only locks parent form?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ownership, owner

I want to open a child form that only locks its parent form. I can't use ShowDialog() because it locks all opened forms until dialog closes.

Main Form
 - Users Form
 - Services Form

When I open a new child form as **Add New User** on Users form, I want **only lock Users form** but I can also open Services form or any other form on Main Form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed an idea from [How-To-Prevent-Control-From-Stealing-Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122341/how-to-prevent-control-from-stealing-focus). Basically, when you open "Add New User", disable the calling form. When "Add New User" closes, enable the calling form. I put an example below.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    Form3 frm3;
    public override bool Focused
    {
        get
        {
            return HasFocus;
        }
    }
    private bool HasFocus = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 

        frm3 = new Form3();

    }

    void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.FormClosed -= frm2_FormClosed;
        this.Enabled = true;
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.FormClosed += frm2_FormClosed;
        frm2.Show();
        this.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm3.Show();
    }
}
```